# Seleção com varias condições de diferenças (SQLSERVER)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de melhorar essa seleção:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id <> 15 AND id <> 17 AND id <> 23 ... id <> N
```

eu não tenho um certo intervalo definido e os `ids` são selecionados pelo checkbox no html, ou seja posso ter N ids. Existe alguma sintaxe no SQL ou SQLServer que possa melhorar esse tipo de consulta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o `IN`, ficaria assim:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (15, 17, 23);
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar o [NOT IN](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189062(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id not in (15, 17, 23/*, N*/)
```